# javascript Inheriting properties from another function

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance

Here is a problem i am not able to solve. I am having a Object called **Person**. I am added a method to it called **changeCol(el, col)** It required two parameters, one is reference to the element and another is te color property. so when we will call this method, this will change the elements color. Now I am attached a new method to the object called **changeSize(size);**. it required one parameter called (size). Now the doubt is when i will called the second method to an element, I want to change the color as well and increase the font size.

In first method i got reference to the element and change the color. so, same thing i don't want to repeat in second method. So, how to inherit first methods parameters to the second method.

Here is the code so far -

```
function Person(){

}
Person.prototype.changeCol = function(el, col){
  var elem = document.getElementById(el);
  elem.style.color = col;
};

Person.prototype.changeSize = function(size){

};



//here we are calling the method
var foo = new Person();
foo.changeCol('paragraph', 'blue');// this is working fine.
foo.changeSize('45px'); // this method will change the size and color as well.
```

Comment: Will the `changeSize()` method be called independantly from the `changeCol()` function at some time, or will they always be called together?

Comment: What's the point of having `changeCol()` be a method of the `Person` prototype when it doesn't do anything with `Person` properties?

Comment: I want to call the changeSize() method separatley. but it will change the color also. So may be the changeCOlor method will execute inside the changeSize method.

Comment: but change colour requires arguments: where are those values intended to come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the elem when you create person using `this.elem` or check if elem is set.

```
function Person(elemID){
  // could set the elem here
  this.elem=false;
}
Person.prototype.changeCol = function(el, col){
  this.elem = this.elem || document.getElementById(el);
  this.elem.style.color = col;
};
Person.prototype.changeSize = function(size){
  this.elem = this.elem || document.getElementById(el);
  ...
};
```

Comment: what is intended to happen to the colour when you call changeSize()? This solution does not help with this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm missing something here, but I don't see how you expect this to work.

```
 var person1 = new Person();
 person1.setSize("45px");   // what should color be set to?

 var person2 = new Person();
 person2.changeColor("p1", green);

 var person3 = new Person();
 person3.setSize("45px");   // what us your intention now?
```

functions simply don't inherit from each other. If you want to set a default value for el and colour across all instances, set them as prototype properties.

Comment: ok, here is the doubt. in person2 object you called changeColor(), so it change the color. But what i want is in person1 object, when we are calling setSize(size);, this method will change the font size and color as well.

Comment: right but how can we know the intended colour for person 1? we've never set any color for anything yet. I don't believe you have a well-defined requriement. I have two explicit questions in my example above, tell me exactly what behaviour you intend